# Offset of next type of element

Tags: jquery

In semantic HTML, I'm trying to find how tall the area is between two header elements. The area between the header elements won't always just be paragraph elements.

```js
var pageWrapper = $('article');
var sections = pageWrapper.find('h2');

sections.each(function(){
  var section = $(this);
  var sectionThisTop = section.offset().top;
  var sectionNextTop = section.next('h2').offset().top;
  var sectionHeight = sectionNextTop - sectionThisTop;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Some intro text</p>
  
  <h2>Subheader One</h2>
  <p>Some text.</p>
  <img src="some.image">
  <p>Some more text.</p>
  
  <h2>Next Subheader</h2>
  <p>The article continues.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: `section.next('h2')` would be undefined.. So better user `section.siblings('h2')`

Comment: Not sure why you don't just wrap your sections in `div`s...

Comment: I'm trying to keep the HTML code free of unnecessary style-only elements. I managed to figure it out:

`var sectionNextTop = section.nextAll('h2').eq(0).offset().top;`